# Query related input of char/int

Tags: java

I'm not able to understand that why is the compiler just shows running(which is forever) when I change char to int in this program. By changing I mean using just int to take the option number and hence using int numbers itself in switch.

This one is normal char 1 which is working-

```
public static void main(String args[])
    throws java.io.IOException{
    char option; int i=0;

    do{
        if(i==1)
            System.out.println("\nNotice: Wrong option chosen, pick again.");
        i=1;
        System.out.println("Help on:");
        System.out.println("1. if");
        System.out.println("2. switch");
        System.out.println("3. while");
        System.out.println("4. do-while");
        System.out.println("5. for");
        System.out.println("Pick any option for brief informatrion.");
        option= (char)System.in.read();
    }while(option<'1' || option>'5');

    switch(option){
        case '1':
            System.out.println("The If:\n");
            System.out.println("If(condition) statement;");
            System.out.println("else statement;");
            break;
        case '2':
            System.out.println("The Switch:\n");
            System.out.println("switch(expression){");
            System.out.println("  case constant:");
            System.out.println("      statement sequence");
            System.out.println("  break;");
            System.out.println("  // ...");
            System.out.println("}");
            break;
        case '3':
            System.out.println("The While:\n");
            System.out.println("while(condition statement;)");
            break;
        case '4':
            System.out.println("The Do-While:\n");
            System.out.println("do{");
            System.out.println("    statement;");
            System.out.println("}while(condition);");
            break;
        case '5':
            System.out.println("The For:\n");
            System.out.println("for(init; condition; iteration){");
            System.out.println("    statement;");
            System.out.println("}");
            break;
    }
}
```

}

This is int 1 which just keeps running forver

```
public static void main(String args[])
    throws java.io.IOException{
    int option; int i=0;

    do{
        if(i==1)
            System.out.println("\nNotice: Wrong option chosen, pick again.");
        i=1;
        System.out.println("Help on:");
        System.out.println("1. if");
        System.out.println("2. switch");
        System.out.println("3. while");
        System.out.println("4. do-while");
        System.out.println("5. for");
        System.out.println("Pick any option for brief informatrion.");
        option= System.in.read();
    }while(option<1 || option>5);

    switch(option){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("The If:\n");
            System.out.println("If(condition) statement;");
            System.out.println("else statement;");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("The Switch:\n");
            System.out.println("switch(expression){");
            System.out.println("  case constant:");
            System.out.println("      statement sequence");
            System.out.println("  break;");
            System.out.println("  // ...");
            System.out.println("}");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("The While:\n");
            System.out.println("while(condition statement;)");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("The Do-While:\n");
            System.out.println("do{");
            System.out.println("    statement;");
            System.out.println("}while(condition);");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("The For:\n");
            System.out.println("for(init; condition; iteration){");
            System.out.println("    statement;");
            System.out.println("}");
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29

The `System.in.read` return an `int` represent for character.

Let's say you type `1`, it will read as `49`.

And if you use file to be `stdin` when it reach `EOF` it will return `-1`

Even if the `char` version, the same error happens.

See this demo: https://ideone.com/Q83qxn